# Port forward rule add failure on Asus router

Tags: router

My Asus router not allows to add port forward by complaining about bad IP:
[image]

Why 192.168.1.252 IP is bad?

```
Router IP is 192.168.1.1 and subnet mask - 255.255.255.0
Product ID  RT-AC87U
Firmware Version    3.0.0.4.382_50702-g6c0e289
```

Comment: What are your LAN settings on the router? Is the network 192.168.1.x and subnet mask of 255.255.255.0?

Comment: Yes, router IP is 192.168.1.1 and subnet mask - 255.255.255.0

Comment: It looks like you have `enable firewall: no` and all other related options are greyed out. It looks like you have IPv6 firewall enabled. In which case, it appears it is expecting IPv6 addresses. Not IPv4. I suspect if you enable the IPv4 firewall a new port forwarding section will appear or it will accept IPv4 addresses. I’m also not convinced this is where you setup port forwarding. It looks more like a firewall ACL list. Provide your router model so we can look at the manual.

Comment: Router model RT-AC87U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I am unable to find an emulator for your exact model it appear the below is very similar:

http://demoui.asus.com/

If you navigate to "WAN" -> "Virtual Server / Port Forwarding" this appears to be the section you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, my router also has "WAN" -> "Virtual Server / Port Forwarding". But what table under Firewall I was trying to use is used for?

Comment: As you cannot put IPv6 addresses into the port forwarding section I assume the section you were using is primarily for port forwarding IPv6. To be honest it is a strange layout... , I assume you have been able to get the port forwarding working now?

Comment: Yes, I got port forward according to your recommendation. But still interesting what does table like port forward does under Firewall section.